# Include multipage PDF using XML

Tags: errors, languages, pdfpages

[image]

I'm new in XSL and LaTeX. I have a project, where I need to include some PDF files. I'm using `\usepackage{pdfpages}`. Everything runs OK, but the main problem is when I want to include a PDF file with several pages and I want to include all of them: it's not working. Here is some problem with `[pages=-]` or `[pages={-}]`. It says

```
! Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file '-'
```

For example here is my code:

```
<xsl:text>
  \includepdf [pages=-]{upload/</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="data/file_name"/><xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
```

Can someone help me please ?

here is all my xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/members">
<xsl:text>%
\documentclass[a4paper,pdftex]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
%\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{19th International Conference on Digital Audio Effects}
    \newpage
</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="user">
        <xsl:text>
      \includepdf [pages=-]{upload/</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="data/file_name"/><xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>
        \end{document}
    </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="file_name">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Part of {upload/</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="data/file_name"/><xsl:text>}</xsl:text> 
is only path to pdf. I'm sure its right

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some more details are needed. How are you producing the TeX file? Can you show the relevant part of it?

Comment: Of course, 
I have xml file with data, xsl file, and I generate it by processor saxon9he.
I'm not sure, what you want to see. 
this is all my code of XSL, where I have latex commands too.

Comment: All my code I show above

Comment: latex seems sees something like `\includepdf-`. So check the output of  saxon, perhaps you must escape the brackets.

Comment: it's  not working still

Comment: How about using `\includepdfset{pages=-}` before the command rather than integrating it via the optional argument?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And again one can see how important *complete* examples are. czech activates the hyphen and so it breaks in the option. Deactivate it first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{-}
\includepdf[pages=-]{testjobname.pdf}
\end{document}
```